# RDP ActiveX Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: c#, terminal-services

In our C# application we use the RDP viewer as an ActiveX control. The application has its own toolbar with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> button. There does not seem to be a method on the ActiveX control to perform this function. I know you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> on your keyboard which is fine but how do I do that from the toolbar button click?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx).

In this example, you could send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> as this:

```
 SendKeys.Send("(^%{END})");
```

Comment: The problem with SendKeys is that is does not work correctly under vista UAC. .NET 3 runtime addresses this but I am tied to .NET 2 right now. See SendKeys MSDN docs for further information.

Comment: Weel, then you probably only have 2 choices. Either upgrade to .NET v3.5 (good) or disable UAC (bad).

Comment: don't you dare disable UAC :) seriously, what you're seeing with SendKeys is totally by design. @Magnus is correct, upgrade to 3.5